# Add a new value to an existing array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have defined an Array List in JavaScript:

```
var arrListContainer = [];
var emptyArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    arrListContainer.push(emptyArray);
}
```

The default value of list is: `[[], [], [], [], []]`

I want to add value to `arrListContainer[2]`, so:

```
arrListContainer[2].push("a");
```

Why the result is `[["a"], ["a"], ["a"], ["a"], ["a"]]`?

I don't understand. I just need `[[], [], ["a"], [], []]`

Thank you!

Comment: Can you replicate your problem into a snippet or create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Try doing like this: `arrListContainer.push([]);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're making each index in `arrListContainer` point to the same object instance, you'll need to create new `emptyArray`s inside your loop (or just push a literal directly)

```
var arrListContainer = [], i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    arrListContainer.push([]);
}
```

---

If you want more clarity, the way you were doing is similar to this

```
var foo = [],
    bar = foo;
foo[2] = 'baz';
// what is bar[2]?
bar[2]; // "baz"
// because
foo === bar; // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You're pushing the same emptyArray instance into each arrListContainer element during the initialisation. So when you later push *"a"* into the second index of it you're effecting the rest of the elements because they all contain the same emptyArray item.

If you change your code to the below, where you don't re-use the same emptyArray variable it works:

```
var arrListContainer = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    arrListContainer.push([]);
}
arrListContainer[2].push("a");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrListContainer = [];
var emptyArray = [];


for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    var emptyArray = [];
    if(i === 2){
        emptyArray.push("a");
    }
    arrListContainer.push(emptyArray);
}


for(var i=0; i< 5; ++i){
    console.log(arrListContainer[i]);
}
```

is this what you want? Try it out in your js file or jsfiddle and take a look at the results from console.